# Hadoop 3.3 and oozie 5.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am using `hadoop 3.3` and `oozie 5.2.0`.

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientImpl.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.async.impl.AMRMClientAsyncImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientAsyncImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.unregisterWithRM(LauncherAM.java:354)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:280)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:155)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1):

There Might be some hadoop3.3 incompatibility oozie 5.2.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3219?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17156510#comment-17156510

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives because there is a current project call Apache Bigtop that compile Hadoop ecosystem tools with new versións. So, you have two options: the first one is use current [Bigtop version 3.1.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Bigtop+3.1.1+Release), who runs over oozie 5.2.1 and hadoop 3.2.4, or using the [Github history changes of Bigtop](https://github.com/apache/bigtop/blob/master/bigtop-packages/src/common/oozie/patch0-hadoop322-hive312.diff) as a reference to compile as your own.
In the other hand, there are some blogs in chinese talking about it like this https://blog.csdn.net/tutu_ai/article/details/124372422

Answer (score 0):

Default Hadoop Version for Oozie 5.2 is 2.6.0

You'd likely need to build Oozie against a newer version of Hadoop

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.0/ENG_Building.html

Comment: Even I tried build oozie 5.2.0 with Hadoop 3.3 .while compiling get an below error

I tried to build Hadoop 3.3 with oozie 5.2.0 , getting below error

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------- [inorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem [ERROR] return type org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.SystemErasureCodingPolicies.ReplicationPolicy is not compatible with org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ErasureCodingPolicy

Comment: tried another method replace hadoop 2.6 with 3.3 jar in oozie , still workflow went fine few times and got failed with below error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientImpl.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.async.impl.AMRMClientAsyncImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientAsyncImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.unregisterWithRM(LauncherAM.java:354)